# ReactJS set state of a component from an other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to pass props or rather states between two components?

I have a `<div>` which is hidden by default, which gets rendered in, let's say `Block1` and a click event in `Block2`. When I click the link in Block2 it should tell or set the state to active in Block 1. How can I do this?

```
class Block1 extends React.Component{
   constructor(){
     super()

     this.state = {
       showElem: false
      }

     render() {
       return() {
        <div>
           {this.state.showElem ? <div data-active={this.state.showElem}/> : null}
        </div>
     }
   }
  }
}


class Block2 extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
      super()

      this.state = {
        showElem: false
      }

      handleClick() {
         this.setState({showElem: !this.state.showElem})
      }

      render() {
         return() {
           <div>
             <a onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Click to show Block1</a>
          </div>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The CSS would be like

```
div {
  display: none;
}

[data-active="true"] {
   display: block
}
```

So, is this even possible?

Comment: You might want to look into flux or redux.

Comment: Hi Steve! can you provide jsfiddle or codepan link?

Comment: There are already several sufficient answers below. But I want to note something; with your code you've not terminated your constructor in either case. Be sure to post complete code so that we have an easier time understanding the problem. At first glance I'd notice you're calling render in on your constructor and wonder why. 

Secondly, if all you intend to do in the constructor is declare state you can save yourself some code and skip the constructor entirely. 

`class Block1 extends React.Component { 
    state = {
        key: value
    };
}`

because state is a class property.

Answer (score 2):

Look into whether `Block`1 and `Block2` are in a tightly coupled relationship. The indication of that would be a parent component either always containing both, or knowing what to do with the click event in case `Block1` is not present, etc. -- i.e. able to gracefully dispatch your state.

If the answer is yes, then you should [lift the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from `Block2` to parent component and pass it to Block1 via props.

If the answer is no and the components can be used independently of each other, then the state change is global to your application. You should, as [Adam Azad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151050/adam-azad) suggests, look into global state management in Redux and have `Block2` generate an action and `Block1` subscribe to any state changes that action might result in.

Comment: I second this answer. If you intend to tightly couple these two components (e.g. you would not render one without the other) then either render them together with a parent component or render one with the other, in which case you can lift state. However, even in a tightly coupled relationship Redux is a great pattern to use for managing component state via props.

Answer (score 0):

If those two components have common parent, you can raise the state and handler method one level up. Something like that:

```
class MightyParent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isBlock1Visible: false,
    }
    this.handleBlock2Click = this.handleBlock2Click.bind(this);
  }

  handleBlock2Click() {
    this.setState({isBlock1Visible: true});
  }

  render() {
    <Block1 isVisible={this.state.isBlock1Visible} />
    <Block2 onClick={this.handleBlock2Click} />
  }
}
```

And than you access the passed props in each block respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible! One of the nice ways to do this in React is to use [render props](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcVAq3YFiuc&t=1164s).  However, for this simple case, you could do something like this:

```
const Block1 = (props) => <div>whatever stuff goes here</div>

class Block2 extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()

    this.state = {
      showElem: false
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ showElem: !this.state.showElem })
  }

  render() {
    const { showElem } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <a onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Click to show Block1</a>
        { showElem &&
            <Block1 />
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Essentially, you are rendering the whole `Block1` element according to the state of `Block2`. If you change `showElem` to true, `Block1` will be rendered, else, this part: `{ showElem && <Block1 /> }` will not render anything, hiding the `Block1` element.